# Spout as socket listener

Tags: java, apache-storm

Since blocking process isn't allowed in Spouts, What is the best approach to implement a Spout as Socket listener to recieve DataGram Packets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the most famous software development rules is:

> We can solve any problem by introducing an extra level of indirection

You can simply send your datagram packets to something like Apache Kafka, HornetQ, RabbitMQ and your Spout will pull the data from there.